# Error running WPF application using ChromiumWebBrowser from CefSharp.Wpf on Windows 8.0 SP1

Tags: windows-8, wpf-controls, cefsharp

I need to use WPF aplication on Win 8.0 with .net 4.6.2
I want to use ChromiumWebBrowser on it.
Unfortunately, when I start the window with that ChromiumWebBrowser component, the application closes with an error in the eventlog.

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at CefSharp.CefSettingsBase..ctor()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.Example.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at CefSharp.Wpf.Example.Program.Main(System.String[])
....
```

Is posible to run application with CefSharp.Wpf on Windows 8.0 SP1?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Instead of building the project from source use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing, making sure you have installed VC++ 2015 or greater.

Comment: If Chrome runs on the machine then CefSharp should run if you have all the required dependencies and deployed all the required files

Comment: I would like to add that I am compiling an application on Windows 10 - VS 2019 and testing on Windows 8.0 SP1 with .Net framework 4.6.2 installed

Comment: CefSharp.MinimalExample not working too, crash with an error. 
   
   
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
   at System
   .Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.String)
   at CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.App.Resolver(System.Object, System.ResolveEventArgs)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.String)

Chrome browser is installed and work fine

Comment: Does it work on your development machine? Have you installed VC++? Looks like you are missing a dependency.

Comment: Yes I have instaled VC++ Development w VS2019 and it work on my dev maschine. I tested it on Windows 10 and Windows 7 and it work fine. Ony on Windows 8.0 doesn't work

Comment: What version of Chrome is installed?

Comment: Chrome version 89.0.4389.90 (32 bit). System is 32bit

Comment: Make sure you have VC++ x86 installed,  download from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0 if chrome runs then it should just be a matter of finding which dependency is missing.

Comment: After installing vc_redist.x86.exe on destination system, the application started working.

Comment: Visual C++ needs to be installed on every computer you plan to run CefSharp on.